# PredictionIO Not able to build pio

Tags: recommendation-engine, predictionio

I am trying to use UR with predictionio-0.11.0-incubating, with following configs:
elasticsearch.version=1.7.6
scala.version=2.11.8

It is giving an error message [ERROR] [Engine$] No engine found. Your build might have failed. Aborting.
It is not listing any detailed exception. Please find below the logs:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/neha/incubator-predictionio-0.11.0-incubating/PredictionIO-0.11.0-incubating/lib/spark/pio-data-hdfs-assembly-0.11.0-incubating.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/neha/incubator-predictionio-0.11.0-incubating/PredictionIO-0.11.0-incubating/lib/pio-assembly-0.11.0-incubating.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.

SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]

[INFO] [Engine$] Using command '/home/neha/incubator-predictionio-0.11.0-incubating/PredictionIO-0.11.0-incubating/sbt/sbt' at /home/neha/projects/universal-recommender to build.

[INFO] [Engine$] If the path above is incorrect, this process will fail.

[INFO] [Engine$] Uber JAR disabled. Making sure lib/pio-assembly-0.11.0-incubating.jar is absent.

[INFO] [Engine$] Going to run: /home/neha/incubator-predictionio-0.11.0-incubating/PredictionIO-0.11.0-incubating/sbt/sbt  package assemblyPackageDependency in /home/neha/projects/universal-recommender

[INFO] [Engine$] Compilation finished successfully.

[INFO] [Engine$] Looking for an engine...

[ERROR] [Engine$] No engine found. Your build might have failed. Aborting.
```

Initial question posted at https://github.com/PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-universal-recommendation/issues/63.

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure the below mentioned points :

- You are running pio build command in the same directory where your engine.json is placed
- Mention scala version scalaVersion := "2.11.8" in your build.sbt